# How to pull a get message from a TCPStream in rust?

Tags: server, tcp, rust, get, stream

I'm trying to pull a get message from a TCPStream in rust, sent to a local server that is set up by the program. What's giving me the most issue is this error here:

expected `&[u8]`, found enum `std::result::Result`

And here's the code it originates from:

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    println!("New Client IP: {}", stream.local_addr().unwrap());
    thread::spawn(|| {
                //should probably call the fn to validate the request somewhere up here
                let mut s = String::new();
                let mut h = String::new();
                let mut buffer = [0; 500];
                let r = str::from_utf8(stream.read_to_string(&mut buffer));
                s.push_str(r);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read the [Error Handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) chapter of the book?

Comment: `read_to_string` alredy writes to the buffer, and it returns a result with whether it succeed or not, not the string itself:
`stream.read_to_string(&mut buffer).expect("Could not read from stream");
let r = str::from_utf8(&buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

Some errors:

- [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) needs a `String` as a buffer, not an array.
- It also returns a [result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/type.Result.html) with the number of bytes read (as `Result<usize>`), not the string itself.

```rust
let mut buffer = String::new();
stream.read_to_string(&mut buffer).expect("Unable to read from buffer");
s.push_str(&buffer);
```

**If** you want to read exactly buffer size **bytes** you need to use [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact)

```rust
let mut buffer = [0; 500];
stream.read_exact(&mut buffer).expect("Unable to read from buffer");
s.push_str(str::from_utf8(&buffer).expect("Invalid utf8 data"));
```

Comment: could I still add a 500 or so byte buffer to it if its a string?

Comment: No, If the type is a string you need to give him a string. @Linx52 check update